# Cast inside the method or let the client code cast, which one is better?

Tags: c#, casting, generics

I have two choices of implementing a method, the first one is a generic type where the client code does not have to cast

```
    public T GetControl<T>(string controlName) where T : Control
    {
        return (T)ControlManager.GetControl( controlName);
        //I simplify the logic here, in my case this is a bit 
        //complicated than this, but the object we get is of the Type Control  
    }
```

client code:

```
MyControl control = GetControl<MyControl>("foo");
```

The second choice is the non-generic one. Here the client code will have to cast

```
    public Control GetControl(string controlName)
    {
        return ControlManager.GetControl(controlName); 
        // I simplify the logic here, in my case this is a bit 
        // complicated than this, but the object we get is of the Type Control  
    }
```

client code:

```
    MyControl control = (MyControl)GetControl("foo");
```

Is one of them better than the other? At first I thought first one is better, because casting (which I think is a bit dirty) is refactored in one method, and don't have to be repeated in all client codes. But since the generic type has to be specified by the client code anyway ([generic methods can't infer return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why)), basically the client code only shift `(MyControl)` in front to `<MyControl>` in the generic parameter, so it's probably not better anyway.

What is your opinion?

Comment: I personally prefer the first but I've also often had a tendency to over-use generics (got a little excited when I first started using them) and have at times caused myself more grief than it was worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using generics here is slightly better, because it means if you decide to change the code in a way that requires knowledge of the type that's being asked for, you can.

The change could be as simple as logging the type, or something much more complicated. For example, it would allow you to have controls with the same name, but different types, if you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the generic method is better for two reasons. First, it's cleaner, both for the client calling it because they don't have to cast and for the process of casting because it is only done in one place. Secondly, the client that's asking for the control knows the type of the control in this instance so it's very sensible, and good practice, to have the client specify that rather than sending back an object just so the client has to cast it. That's why generics exist.

However, I recommend in your code in the method you use the **as** operator rather than a cast because even though the client calling you specified the type, the as operator will simply return null instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Isn't returning null a bad practice (I remember reading this somewhere)? And in my case, if the cast failed, the client cannot do anything anyway, then isn't it better that the exception reads "cast failure" instead of a nasty nullreference exception?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using `as` here. If there is a mistake, you want to know about it as soon as possible and you want to know what exactly is the mistake. Cast does that: it immediately throws an `InvalidCastException` that explains what happened. Using `as` would mean you will most likely get `NullReferenceException` sometime after calling this method, that's confusing (which object exactly is `null`?) and too late.

Comment: @svick, duly noted, that is something I'll consider in my future endeavors as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this, suppose you wanted to get the control and invoke some method on it but didn't necessarily want to declare a variable for it.  Well a "pre-casted" return type will be much better than casting yourself.  Which would you prefer?

```
GetControl<MyControl>("MyControlName").MyMethod();

((MyControl)GetControl("MyControlName")).MyMethod();
```

I *hope* you'd say the generic version is better.  With a cast, you are required to wrap in parentheses due to the lower precedence.

If you have the opportunity to return the most appropriate type (statically or generically), try to make it happen.  Having to perform a cast on the result of a method call is a sign of a problem nowadays IMHO.  It's almost as bad as returning type `object`.

Casting is ugly.  This is one of the reasons I'd imagine why there are extension methods on existing objects that does something similar.  [`DataRow.Field<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field.aspx) and [`DataRow.SetField<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.setfield.aspx) come to mind which allows you to read or write a column in a data row.

Comment: I think the `Field()` method is there mostly to deal with `DBNull`. But that's part of the reason why use generics in cases like this: you can do more complicated things with the type internally.